# Visual Studio 2013 upgrade 3 no windows phone project option?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to create my first windows phone app but i can't find the project type.

Is there any trick to getting the option to appear.

I have the latest update installed.

[image: 1]

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the SDK? It has to be checked during the installation process or else you will not have the option available to you.

http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk

Then the menu point should appear. Note under Windows 8.x the project will be under store apps.

[image: Windows Phone Project under Windows 8.x is under Store Apps / Windows Phone Apps]

Comment: I had to reinstall vs and select it there.